# It takes ~ 10 attempts to start my mid 2012 (first with retina) MBP 15

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, startup, damage

It was 2019 October when I used the computer on the rain. For a few days I had some troubles with touchpad, then it completely recovered itself, then the entire machine died. Since then I was able to use the laptop maybe 5 times.

At first it didn't start up at all, then it started once with no touchpad nor keyboard response, laggy as hell. Then, after few months following situation repeats: when connected to power there is blickering catalog icon until battery is dead or disconnected in a hard way. It hardly ever starts up properly, and if it does so, it works perfectly fine each time. Is it a hard drive? I have OWD disk, I don't know history of the computer. A guy in local 3rd  party apple shop told me that the keyboard, touchpad and maybe hard drive need replacement, the hard drive can die anytime soon. Here is an error code:

```
Anonymous UUID:       5ED475D8-87D1-D4B7-DEBA-59B706F76473

Tue Jan  1 01:00:15 2019

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 5 caller 0xffffff800a4bb0ef):  initproc exited -- exit reason namespace 2 subcode 0xa description: none

uuid info:
 0x105e9d000    uuid = <d3e77331-ace5-349d-a7cc-433d626d4a5b>
 0x1008ac000    uuid = <bbd445b6-fba9-3a9c-828f-a112f63e2080>

Thread 3 crashed

RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x00000001008fa068, RCX: 0x00000001008f7000, RDX: 0x00000001008fa088
RSP: 0x00007000057c8300, RBP: 0x00007000057c83a0, RSI: 0x00000001008fa078, RDI: 0x00000001008ac000
R8:  0x00000001008acae8, R9:  0x0000000000000d0e, R10: 0x0000000000000010, R11: 0x0000000000000206
R12: 0x0000000100025375, R13: 0x0000000000001eb0, R14: 0x00000001008fc748, R15: 0x00000001008ac000
RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0x00007fff6c0d8b7f, CS:  0x000000000000002b, SS:  0x0000000000000023

Thread 0: 0xffffff802b7b7520
    0x00007fff6c213126
    0x00007fff6c09cede
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 1: 0xffffff8031544000
    0x00007fff6c22e29e
    0x00007fff6c08fde6
    0x00007fff6c09ef42
    0x00007fff6c093792
    0x00007fff6c094396
    0x00007fff6c09c6ed
    0x00007fff6c2cd611
    0x00007fff6c2cd3fd
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 2: 0xffffff802f51ea40
    0x00007fff6c2cd3f0

Thread 3: 0xffffff8034d98a40
    0x00007fff6c0d8b7f
    0x00007fff6c0d8a07
    0x00007fff6c0d88d1
    0x00007fff6c135b2a
    0x00000001008d1375
    0x00000001008de439
    0x00007fff6c08d63d
    0x00007fff6c08fde6
    0x00007fff6c09ef42
    0x00007fff6c093792
    0x00007fff6c094396
    0x00007fff6c09c6ed
    0x00007fff6c2cd611
    0x00007fff6c2cd3fd
    0x8000120000000000

Thread 4: 0xffffff80321e0000
    0x00007fff6c2cd3f0

Thread 5: 0xffffff80311e6a40
    0x00007fff6c2cd3f0


Mac OS version:
18G87

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Thu Jun 20 18:42:21 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.270.47~4/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 982F17B3-0252-37FB-9869-88B3B1C77335
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)
Root disk errors: "Could not recover SATA HDD after 5 attempts. Terminating."

EOF
Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM 257.0.0.0.0, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2,3 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: kHW_IntelHD4000Item, Intel HD Graphics 4000, spdisplays_builtin
Graphics: kHW_NVidiaGeForceGT650MItem, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, spdisplays_pcie_device, 1 GB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.190.33 AirPortDriverBrcm4360-1325.2)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.14d3, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: OWC Aura, 240,06 GB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

What should I do?

Comment: "It was 2019 October when I used the computer on the rain"  Do you mean that the computer got *wet*?

Comment: Yes, it got wet.

Comment: It’s liquid damage and you need to take it in for repair.  There’s likely corroded electrical contacts somewhere and it’s only going to get worse. Have a look at [Rossman Repair](https://www.rossmanngroup.com/) in NYC.